# php image file upload- php× 241958

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and copied this code from a book. In the file upload.html:

```
 <form method="POST" action="do_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="img1" size="30"></p>
```

In the PHP script do_upload.php:

```
if($_FILES["img1"] != "") {
    echo "file selected"; else die("Couldnot copy the file");
}
```

But I got a error saying:

> Undefined index: img1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test23\do_upload.php on line
>   2

Why is img1 termed as `undefined index` even though `name="img1"` is in
upload.html?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML you have for the form and this file input?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't select a file, then `$_FILES['img1']` won't exist.

If you don't have uploads enabled on your server, then `$_FILES` won't exist.

Make sure of both of the above.